# Why a plaine website has bad optimization metrics?

Tags: web-development, seo-audit, technical-seo

We could think that create a website in HTML and CSS with a couple of images and just a few actions in Javascript could have good metrics if it's well designed. But tests like Chrome Lighthouse show bad results.

Which are the basic optimizations that may help a simple website needs be over 70% in Lighthouse?

Comment: "How do I optimize a website" is a huge question.  Even for a "simple" website there are many things that you can do.  Please ask more specific questions about various aspects of optimization.  Start by following the advice given to you by the tools that are telling you that your site needs to be optimized.

Comment: It's not about "How do I optimize a website". It's about which are the basic improvement that impact on optimization to increase it over the 70%

Comment: That isn't something that can be answered in a few paragraphs here.   If you are having trouble with a more specific problem, please ask about that.

Answer (score 1):

Programs like Lighthouse also tell you why they rated the site the way they did.  To solve your particular problem we would need the website and/advice from the report.

It can be any number of things we can only guess at - slow hosting, webserver negotiation/configuration errors, lack of bandwidth, bad/blocking javascript, third party javascript being slow, dns issues, https negotiation issues.   Things like caching settings can matter as well.

Also  for images, sometimes compression is not enough. Sometomes the images themselves need re-evaluation as even compressed images can be too large.

Comment: Right, but I talking about the thing we can do "a priori". That we can improve over the site.

Comment: Other then ensure your pages are small and Javascript is not blocking, not much.